# Error Inserting Data Into SQL Compact

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-ce

I want to insert this piece of data into SQL Compact 3.5 using the following code

```
INSERT INTO [[2 Letter Words]] ([Word],[Melted]) VALUES (N'AA',N'AA');
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Error Code: 80040E14
Message   : There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 39,Token in error = , ]
Minor Err.: 25501
Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
Num. Par. : 1
Num. Par. : 39
Err. Par. : ,
```

What's wrong?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Server onlys likes a single set of brackets in `[Table Name with spaces]`.

```
 INSERT INTO [2 Letter Words] ([Word],[Melted]) VALUES (N'AA',N'AA');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the doble "[ ]" in table's name.

```
INSERT INTO [2 Letter Words] ([Word],[Melted]) VALUES (N'AA',N'AA');
```